How can I change the codeblock color in R markdown documents in VS Code?
I cant figure out the setting to add to change the color of codeblocks in R markdown documents (lighter color int he attached) in VScode.
I can edit others, such as
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "[Monokai Night]": {
    "editor.background": "#191919"
  }


what language support extension are you using for R markdown?

R Extension for Visual Studio Code v2.8.4
